# Linux Sort Command Doesn't Include Bottom 9 and 14 Lines in Two Text Files

Tags: sort

Hi I have a peculiar issue... when I run the Linux sort command to sort two text files, 3331 lines and 4344 lines each, only the 3317 and 4335 topmost lines are included in the output files.  Here are the commands I am running:

```
sort -o contactspreservesort.csv contactspreserve.csv
sort -o contactsdeletesort.csv contactsdelete.csv
```

I have tried this as well:

```
sort contactspreserve.csv > contactspreservesort.csv
sort contactsdelete.csv > contactsdeletesort.csv
```

Any ideas what's going on?
Thanks

Comment: Does the contactspreservesort.csv and contactsdeletesort.csv have repeated values? Does these files have more than one value for each line?

Comment: Could you publish your files?

Comment: @Paulo There are duplicate lines in both lists but far more than the number of lines that are not sorted from the end of each file.  What do you mean when you say values?  The files are Google contacts lists in csv format.

Comment: How do you count the lines?

Comment: @Kusalananda Using Notepad++.

Comment: @JoshOrenberg What does `wc -l` report on the two sets of files on the command line?

Comment: @JoshOrenberg I do not see such behavior on my system. Which version of the `sort` utility do you use? What shows `echo $LANG,$LC_ALL,$LC_COLLATE`?

Comment: @Jesse_b Even if the files had DOS text line-endings, they would sort ok. I'm wondering whether it's an issue with Notepad++ misunderstanding the data somehow. If the data was _pasted_ into the editor, for example, there might be issues.

Comment: @Kusalananda wc reports the same as Notepad++

Comment: @edo1 Did you try using the files I linked to?  Did you get the same number of lines for the sorted files as for the sources of the sort commands?  For sort I'm using v 8.28.  The echo command shows "C.UTF-8,,"

Comment: @Kusalananda I manually checked that the last 9 and 14 of the source file lines were not included in the sorted files.

Comment: edo@edo-home:/tmp/123$ LANG=C.UTF8 sort < contactspreserve.csv |wc -l
3331

Comment: (1) You say that `sort` is excluding the last 9 lines of `contactsdelete.csv`, but have you actually verified that?  Have you verified that `contactsdeletesort.csv` contains the first 4335 lines of `contactsdelete.csv` (but sorted), and the last 9 lines are missing?  Or have you only observed that the output file has 9 lines too few?  (2) If you make a copy of `contactsdelete.csv` (let’s call it `a4335`) and delete the last 9 lines (so `a4335` contains the first 4335 lines of `contactsdelete.csv`), and then sort *that* (`a4335`), what do you get?  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … (3) If you make a copy of `contactsdelete.csv` (let’s call it `a9`) and delete the first 4335 lines (so `a9` contains the last 9 lines of `contactsdelete.csv`), and then sort that (`a9`), what do you get?  (4) If you sort `contactsdeletesort.csv` (the output from `sort`), what do you get?  (You should get a file identical to `contactsdeletesort.csv`.) … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @edo1 Thanks dude I tried that same command on my computer and it worked!  So I figured out the issue was isolated to the Python script I was using.  Replaced the os.system calls at the end of the script with a separate bash script and now everything is working fine.

Comment: @G-Man I know the last lines were excluded because I did a manual search for the 10 lines before the first line that was excluded and they were all in the sorted text file.  When I searched for the bottom 10 lines they were not.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know it's the bottom lines that are missing, and the topmost that are preserved? Just because the file is shorter does not mean the last lines fell off, just that some got lost somewhere.

Show a full wc of all 4 files, not just wc -l. We might find all (or most of) the characters are there. Maybe some 'false' lines got joined up because of a few CRs (should not happen, but then neither should the whole thing).

Where are your sort work files going? Maybe it is /tmp, and maybe it is almost full.

Run sort, and echo the status afterwards.

I can post an awk that will tell you exactly which lines got lost, which might help explain what is going on. (Diff won't work if the files are sorted differently -- you get a huge report.)

Maybe some lines are too long. I can't remember the limit (if there is one). I can post an awk to show the max line length too.

Raises the next question. What OS, what version, what machine. SunOS used to be flaky with long lines, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody.  I found the source of the problem.  I tried piping the output of the sort command to wc -l and the line count was reported correctly for both csv files.  So after a little trial and error I figured out the issue was isolated to the Python script I was using.  I replaced the os.system calls for sorting the files using the sort command at the end of the script with a separate bash shell script and now everything is working fine.  I am using Python 3.6.7 and Bash Shell as bundled with the Ubuntu Linux subsystem as part of Windows 10.

Comment: This answer contains a lot of info that would have been helpful in tracking down the issue, had it been part of  the question.

Comment: Sorry but I had no idea where to start in the first place.